# Regex validator allowing empty as an input

Tags: asp.net, validation

Shouldn't this regex validator make sure the user enters something in the textbox?  For some reason an empty textbox passes through.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revNumericValidator" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"
                    ControlToValidate="tb1" ErrorMessage="Please enter blah (must be a number)." />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Validators by convention don't validate empty text.  If you want to require a value, you have to *also* add a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) says

> Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) control in addition to the **RegularExpressionValidator** control.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is the case, but with the ASP.NET validator controls I have always had to combine a RegEx validator with a Required field validator, as the RegEx one only seems to fire if there is text included in the field.