# allow empty textbox, but don't allow invalid input

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have the following code to validate an email address:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPersonalEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PersonalEmail") %>' Width="185px" />                      
<%-- validate for a valid email address entered--%>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*This is not a valid email address" ValidationExpression="\S+@\S+\.\S+" ControlToValidate="txtPersonalEmail"/>
```

An email address is NOT required BUT if an email address is entered, it has to be in the correct format. At the moment, an incorrectly formatted email address can be entered, it returns an error message but the value in the text box can still be submitted.

any suggestions on how to prevent an incorrectly formatted email being submitted, but still allow a blank value?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The `RegularExpressionValidator` should allow blank values.

Comment: Then remove the `RequiredFieldValidator` that you haven't shown us ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex validator allowing empty as an input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777993/regex-validator-allowing-empty-as-an-input)

Comment: Guess i wasn't clear enough.  An email address is NOT required BUT if an email address is entered, it has to be in the correct format.  At the moment, an incorrectly formatted email address can still be submitted

Comment: @IanMitz ah so the question is really "What is a good email validation regex"?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev no, my validation regex seems to work fine.  If I enter an incorrectly formatted email, RegularExpressionValidator writes a message to a label BUT I can still submit the incorrectly formatted email.  I don't want that.  I want to be able to submit either nothing or a correct email

Comment: @IanMitz ah so the question is really "Why is my form submitting when my RegularExpressionValidator isn't valid"?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I guess that's another way of putting it.

Comment: @IanMitz well, you need to include more code. Since it is writing the error message out when user tries to submit a bad email, that implies it is working. You don't explain how you get past that error message to then submit the form (although clicking the button showed the error message and didn't submit form??). This part is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i got your question now you should try any of the following regular expression .. Please let me know for any other query

```
1) ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]){1,70}$"

2) ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" (As suggested by James Johnson in his answer)
```

have you combined `RegularExpressionValidator` with `RequiredFieldValidator` ??

as far as i know `RegularExpressionValidator` will allow blank in the textbox unless you have combined it with required field validator

Comment: @MikeSmithDev ok .. and i was thinking may be i was wrong but now i am sure

Comment: Yes, no input is required unless enforced by the regex.

Comment: @Dhaval yes you are correct. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) states 'Validation succeeds if the input control is empty'.

Comment: @Dhaval  see my attempt at clarification under my original post.  I want to allow blank UNLESS there is something in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The `RegularExpressionValidator` is definitely what you want, or you could use a `CustomValidator` if warranted too. If the validator is giving you problems, you may want to use a different regex.

This one works pretty well:

```
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

I don't recall whether it's available for this particular validator, but there may be a `ValidateEmptyText` property you can leverage:

```
ValidateEmptyText="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to validate with both **RequiredFieldValidator** and **RegularExpressionValidator**.

**RequiredFieldValidator** validates whether the textbox is blank.

**RegularExpressionValidator** validates whether the email address entered in the textbox is valid.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="Server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
   ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" Display="Dynamic" 
   Text="(Required)"
   ErrorMessage="Email is required." 
   runat="Server" 
   ID="EmailRequiredFieldValidator" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
   ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" 
   Text="(Invalid)"
   ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
   ErrorMessage="The e-mail address you specified is not well-formed."
   runat="Server" 
   ID="EmailRegularExpressionValidator"
   Display="Dynamic" />
```